# Where is my log?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running a Flask project. I was trying to logging all logs from debug level to console. Here is my code:

```
#!flask/bin/python
import logging

from app import app

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format = '%(asctime)s [%(process)d %(name)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s')
logging.debug('test')
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.debug('test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'crazy'
    log.debug('test')
    app.run(host =  '0.0.0.0', port = 8100, debug = True, processes = 8)
```

Here is the result (one of the weird thing is there are two 'crazy' printed):

```
(flask) [felixc@diamond flask]$ ./run.py 
crazy
crazy
```

I cannot find anything on console. There is even no 'test' displayed on the console. So where is my logs?
My Python is v2.7.13 on CentOS 6.9.

Update the logging with basicConfig:

```
(flask) [felixc@diamond flask]$ ipython
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jun 22 2017, 13:33:06) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: edit
IPython will make a temporary file named: 
/tmp/ipython_edit_pUodOs/ipython_edit_WWATn8.py
Editing... done. Executing edited code...
Out[1]: "import logging\nlogging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format = '%(asctime)s [%(process)d %(name)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s')\n"

In [2]: logging.debug('test')
2017-12-12 14:51:06,042 [14863 root] DEBUG test
```

Comment: I am not sure you will see anything without adding a handler of some sort.

Comment: You might want to read through https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html if you haven't done so already

Comment: (flask) [felixc@diamond flask]$ ipython
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jun 22 2017, 13:33:06) 
IPython 5.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: edit
IPython will make a temporary file named: /tmp/ipython_edit_pUodOs/ipython_edit_WWATn8.py
Editing... done. Executing edited code...
Out[1]: "import logging\nlogging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format = '%(asctime)s [%(process)d %(name)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s')\n"

In [2]: logging.debug('test')
**2017-12-12 14:51:06,042 [14863 root] DEBUG test**

Comment: I'm unable to read that mess. If you think it's relevant, please format it properly into your question.

Comment: I added the output in ipython with only logging.basicConfig. It seems it works without any handlers.

Comment: That seems relevant. Please add it to your question. The comment is to all intents and purposes illegible.

Comment: Well, there is no such level as `fatal` asfaik. Just change `fatal` to `debug` for example. Or any other level you want.

Comment: actually i tried debug, error, info....

Comment: Just to be sure: you do realize that the block below your `if` statement will be executed only if you run it as a module? Ie not directly from python shell.

Comment: Yes I totally understand it. Maybe I should update the question again.

Comment: Ok, I'm deleting my answer, because now it doesn't make any sense :) I'm sorry but I don't know why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the root reason. I was trying to use Ansible in my project but seems any import will cause the logging not working. I didn't peep into the source code of Ansible yet but I used a test code then discovered it.

```
#!flask/bin/python
import logging

from collections import namedtuple

from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
#from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
#from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
#from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format = '%(asctime)s [%(process)d %(name)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s')
logging.debug('test')
logging.info('test2')
logging.error('test3')
```

Any import from Ansible module causes the logging disappearing. I'll try to find why. My Ansible version is 2.4.2.0